# SqlBulkInsert with a DataTable to a Linked Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert, linked-server

I'm working with 2 SQL 2008 Servers on different machines. The server names are `source.ex.com`, and `destination.ex.com`.

`destination.ex.com` is linked to `source.ex.com` and the appropriate permissions are in place for `source.ex.com` to write to a database called `bacon-wrench` on  `destination.ex.com`

I've logged into `source.ex.com` via SMS and tested this query (successfully):

```sql
INSERT INTO [destination.ex.com].[bacon-wrench].[dbo].[tblFruitPunch]
(PunchID, BaconID) VALUES (4,6);
```

In a C# .NET 4.0 WebPage I connect to `source.ex.com` and perform a similar query (successfully):

```cs
using(SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SOURCE"].ConnectionString))
{
    c.Open();
    String sql = @"
        INSERT INTO [destination.ex.com].[bacon-wrench].[dbo].[tblFruitPunch]
        (PunchID, BaconID) VALUES (34,56);";
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, c))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

For small sets of insert statements (say 20 or less) doing something like this performs fine:

```cs
using(SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SOURCE"].ConnectionString))
{
    c.Open();
    String sql = @"
        INSERT INTO [destination.ex.com].[bacon-wrench].[dbo].[tblFruitPunch]
         (PunchID, BaconID) VALUES (34,56);
        INSERT INTO [destination.ex.com].[bacon-wrench].[dbo].[tblFruitPunch]
         (PunchID, BaconID) VALUES (22,11);
        INSERT INTO [destination.ex.com].[bacon-wrench].[dbo].[tblFruitPunch]
         (PunchID, BaconID) VALUES (33,55);
        INSERT INTO [destination.ex.com].[bacon-wrench].[dbo].[tblFruitPunch]
         (PunchID, BaconID) VALUES (1,2);";
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, c))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do something like this with around 20000 records. The above method takes 11 minutes to complete -- which I assume is the server sreaming at me to make it some kind of bulk operation. From other StackOverflow threads the `SqlBulkCopy` class was recommended and it takes as a parameter `DataTable`, perfect!

So I build a DataTable and attempt to write it to the server (fail):

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("PunchID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("BaconID", typeof(int));
for(int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
{
    //I realize this would make 20000 duplicate 
    //rows but its not important 
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
        11, 33 
    });
}

using(SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SOURCE"].ConnectionString))
{
    c.Open();
    using(SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(c))
    {
        bulk.DestinationTableName = "[destination.ex.com].[bacon-wrench].[dbo].[tblFruitPunch]";
        bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("PunchID", "PunchID");
        bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("BaconID", "BaconID");
        bulk.WriteToServer(dt);
    }
}
```

EDIT2: The below message is what I'm attempting to fix:

The web page crashes at `bulk.WriteToServer(dt);` with an error message `Database bacon-wrench does not exist please ensure it is typed correctly.` What am I doing wrong? How do I change this to get it to work?

EDIT1:

I was able to speed up the query significantly using the below syntax. But it is still very slow for such a small record set.

```cs
using(SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SOURCE"].ConnectionString))
{
    c.Open();
    String sql = @"
        INSERT INTO [destination.ex.com].[bacon-wrench].[dbo].[tblFruitPunch]
         (PunchID, BaconID) VALUES 
         (34,56),
         (22,11),
         (33,55),
         (1,2);";
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, c))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a number of things including linked server settings, collations, synonyms, etc., I eventually got to this error message:

`Inserting into remote tables or views is not allowed by using the BCP utility or by using BULK INSERT.`

Perhaps you can bulk insert to a staging table on your local server (your code works fine for this) and then insert from that staging table to your linked server from there, followed by a local delete of the staging table.  You'll have to test for performance.

Comment: Oh Noes! I will try as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2008+, you can introduce a Table user datatype. Prepare the type, receiving table and stored procedure something like below. Data type and stored procedure is on the local system. I generally have an if statement in the code detecting whether the table is remote or local, remote I do this, local I use SqlBulkCopy.

```
if(TYPE_ID(N'[Owner].[TempTableType]') is null)
begin
CREATE TYPE [Owner].[TempTableType] AS TABLE ( [PendingID] uniqueidentifier, [Reject] bit)
end
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [LinkedServer].[DatabaseOnLS].sys.tables where name = 'TableToReceive') 
EXEC('
CREATE TABLE [DatabaseOnLS].[Owner].[TableToReceive] ( [PendingID] uniqueidentifier, [Reject] bit)
') AT [LinkedServer]
else
EXEC('
TRUNCATE TABLE [DatabaseOnLS].[Owner].[TableToReceive]
') AT [LinkedServer]

CREATE PROCEDURE [Owner].[TempInsertTable]
@newTableType TempTableType readonly
AS
BEGIN
insert into [LinkedServer].[DatabaseOnLS].[Owner].[TableToReceive] select * from @newTableType 
END
```

In the C# code you can then do something like this to insert the DataTable into the table on the linked server (I'm using an existing UnitOfWork, which already have a connection and transaction):

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("TempInsertTable",
                    oUoW.Database.Connection as SqlConnection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }
                )
{
    command.Transaction = oUoW.Database.CurrentTransaction as SqlTransaction;
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@newTableType", oTempTable));
    drResults = command.ExecuteReader();
    drResults.Close();
}
```